# IntelliJ doesn't recognize maven dependencies that are "provided"

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

IntelliJ is not able to resolve the dependencies in my project that have been marked as `provided` in my `pom.xml`. The JAR's have all been downloaded and are present in the `.m2/repository` directory.

How do I fix this? I'm using build 172.3757.52 of the community edition of IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.2.

Below is the `pom.xml` file:

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    my-solr
    my-solr
    0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    MySolr

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <okhttp.version>3.6.0</okhttp.version>
    <guava.version>19.0</guava.version>
    <commons-lang.version>3.6</commons-lang.version>
    <commons-collections.version>4.1</commons-collections.version>
    <commons-io.version>2.5</commons-io.version>
    <jackson-csv.version>2.7.0</jackson-csv.version>
    <solr.version>6.6.0</solr.version>
    <lombok.version>1.16.16</lombok.version>
    <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.1</slf4j.version>
    <joda.time.version>2.8.1</joda.time.version>
    <commons.logging.version>1.1.1</commons.logging.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>${lombok.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
        <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
        <version>${okhttp.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>${guava.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-lang.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-collections.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-io.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
        <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
        <version>${solr.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
        <artifactId>solr-test-framework</artifactId>
        <version>${solr.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
        <artifactId>solr-core</artifactId>
        <version>${solr.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>${commons.logging.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>${joda.time.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
    <build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.properties</include>
                <include>**/*.vm</include>
                <include>**/*.xml</include>
                <include>**/*.xsd</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>log4j.xml</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/test/java</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.properties</include>
                <include>**/*.vm</include>
                <include>**/*.xml</include>
                <include>**/*.xsd</include>
            </includes>
        </testResource>
        <testResource>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources</directory>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.16</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                    <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                    <version>2.16</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar> -->
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <finalName>${project.name}-${project.version}</finalName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dist</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <!-- mvn package -P dist -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6</version>
                    <inherited>false</inherited>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>copy-resources</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                                <resources>
                                    <resource>
                                        <directory>${project.basedir}/target/</directory>
                                        <includes>
                                            <include>${project.name}-${project.version}.jar</include>
                                        </includes>
                                    </resource>
                                </resources>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.9</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/dependencies</outputDirectory>
                                <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                                <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                                <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: Add your pom file here.

Comment: clean and compile again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you import your project? What always works from me is the following: 
Go to File -> Open then select the pom.xml file and import it as a new project. Make sure you overwrite the previous one if any

Answer (score 1):

I've seen Idea having this strange behavior from time to time. Try deleting all idea-based files from your project, then close and re-open the project and re-import all your dependencies - always helps me when I encounter this issue.